# android: set qos for mqtt published message

Tags: android, mqtt, publish

I want an android app to publish a mqtt message with qos 2. Where can I define, that the message has to be published with qos 2? (Defauls seems to be qos 0)

Sample code:

```
mqttHelper.mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, message);

mqttHelper.mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, message, qos=2);
```

The first line publishes the message with qos 0.
The second line gives the error: "cannot resolve symbol "qos".

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is no publish method which takes 3 parameters. You can look [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.html#publish(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20boolean)) for the documentation of the mqttAndroidClient's publish method.

The line you would want to use would probably be -

`mqttHelper.mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, message, 2, false);`

*note that this does not retain the messages, use `true` if you want to retain the messages instead.